# How to compare and change value of constrain programatically?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout

I have given constrains to UIImageView from xib. Now from code I can get all constrains of that image by code `imageview.constraints` . Now I want to change trailing , leading, top and bottom constrains constant values. I have loop through and my code is as below:

```
for constrain in imageview.constraints
{

    if  constrain.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing
    {
        constrain.constant = hPadding
    }
    if constrain.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Leading
    {
        constrain.constant = hPadding
    }
    if constrain.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Top
    {
        constrain.constant = vPadding
    }
    if constrain.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom
    {
        constrain.constant = vPadding
    }
}
```

But non of the conditions are excited. Please help me to solve issue. What I am missing?

Comment: Have you added it from XIB of Storyboard? Please add the image after expanding the relevant constraints. Also keep a breakpoint and print how many constraint you get from `imageview.constraints`

Comment: @Pooja Shah in imageview.constraints, it only takes height and width...log `imageview.constraints` and you are able to know the problem....you have to loop through its superview..